# Java Grad Calculator. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to put together a Java grade calculator for an assignment I'm doing for school. I'm trying to code the `console` class that's in my textbook, but I'm having a frustrating problem and I don't know why. In the method below, the statement `number = getInt(sc3, prompt);` gives me an error that says:

> `no suitable method found for getInt(Scanner,String)`

but the method is typed exactly how it appears in the book, although my variable names are a little different. Why am I getting this error?

```
public static int getInt(String prompt, int minimum, int maximum) {
    int number = 0;
    boolean isValid = false; 
    while (!isValid) {
        number = getInt(sc3, prompt);
        if (number <= minimum) {
            System.out.println("Error. User entry nust be greater than" + " " + minimum + " " + ".");
        } else if (number >= maximum) {
            System.out.println("Error. User entry must be less than" + " " + maximum + " " + ".");
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

[image: textbook]

Comment: There's no defined method here called `getInt` which accepts those parameters.  (whatever `sc3` is and a `String`, specifically)  Either you've made a mistake in copying the course materials or the course materials contain an error.  (Which does indeed happen.)

Comment: There must be another `getInt` function in the materials somewhere? Note the that `getInt` function above has (String, int, int) as arguments/parameters, so there should be another `getInt` function that has (Scanner, String) as the arguments/parameters.

Comment: Can you show what is written in the book that you copied?

Comment: I have pictures of it, but I dont know how to share them.

Comment: You can edit your question and you will find an image icon which you can used to share images, or simply using Ctrl+G.

Comment: Comments assume that's the wrong method. The other possibility is that your call is wrong, and that you should have written this: `number = getInt(prompt, min, max)` (or with appropriate int literals for min/max).

Comment: There should be a method with signature like `public static int getInt(Scanner sc3, String prompt) { ...` in the next couple of pages